# Who is Tao Ren's wife?

Tags: shaman-king

In the original *Shaman King*, in the ending chapter, grown-up Ren already has a kid, named Men. Who is the mother? As when Lyserg wants to reveal it, because it's obvious from the kid's hair color and name, but Ren doesn't allow him to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's implied to be Iron Maiden Jeanne, based on the (silver) hair and (red) eye color.

[image: Men]
[image: Men's mom]

Comment: excellent reference, and nice image, +1!